# Keeping projects in sync across multiple .NET versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build-process

I need to create some core libraries within my application which will be available in both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0. I'm happy creating multiple projects, creating the required defines and using `#ifdef` to control which code make it into which output assembly.

However, what I would like to know is if there is a way of keeping those projects in sync? When I am developing under XNA, I have a Windows build and a Windows Phone build - and XNA injects a property into the project file called `XnaCrossPlatformGroupID`. What it does with that is enable Visual Studio to automagically make sure that when a file is added to a project, it is added to the corresponding project. So, for example, if I add a file called `Foo.cs` to the Windows copy of my project, then that same file is added to the Windows Phone copy of the project.

Is there any way of replicating that sort of behaviour for a normal set of projects within Visual Studio? I would prefer not to use build configurations, as I would like to be able to compile all targeted platforms in a single step, without resorting to tools outside of the IDE (something like TeamCity, for instance). Or is there another method that allows a project to be built against multiple targets without peppering the solution with 20 different build configurations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I do is:

- have one "regular" csproj that I use for most of my dev, adding files etc - but remembering that *really* all files are "in"
- for the other csproj, use something like:

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\Foo\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```

(that is basically the same as "add as link", but without needing to be done on a per-file basis)

This is a recursive include of all *.cs files, so everything is in. No file maintenance needed.

---

If you were trying to target multiple **frameworks** (rather than multiple *versions*), then another option might be: use a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx). This is a single project that works on multiple frameworks, **but** is limited to the strict intersection of features from the platforms you target. In VS2010 this is an add-in feature; it is included by default in VS 11.

Comment: That recursive include thing is cool - but the one flaw I see is that even if some file were missing you couldn't see it in the solution explorer (which makes things easier).

I also tried the portable class library bit - but it is too restrictive and doesn't help when certain files change across platforms. I also have to compile my code on Android and iOS (using MonoDroid and MonoTouch).

Comment: @ananthonline I've been using the recursive thing on protobuf-net for 4 years; has never led to a problem :)

Comment: I am *loving* that. I had read about Portable Class Libraries - but is it possible to use those to target multiple .NET Framework versions? I must admit I was a little lame and didn't try it out because it looked like they were targeting portability across platforms rather than Framework versions...

Comment: @MarcGravell That is VERY interesting - I will definitely try it out. Is there a conditional include mechanism also?

Comment: I'm accepting this (and I'm hugely surprised it only got my vote!). But I tried out Portable Class Libraries and couldn't see a way to make them target multiple .NET versions (under VS2010 at least). So unless I'm missing something, it might be worth removing that bit.

Comment: @MattWhitfield ah, sorry; at that point my head must have been in "alternative platforms" mode rather than "alternative versions"; will tidy that

Comment: How do you prevent the Include from picking up AssemblyInfo.cs?  My VS 2012 is throwing building errors citing duplicate assembly attributes.

Answer (score 0):

What I do with my cross platform projects is to have different slns, each for one platform.

The shared code lives in a common location and is added "as a link" into the correct csproj's. This csproj also contain any platform specific files. If a "common code" file needs to be conditional based on current platform you can choose to replace that with two platform-specific files or put a #ifdef in it (depends on how much of it is different).

Note that you can also add one solution to another inside Visual Studio. This "combined" solution can be used for automated builds for all platforms.

Example: https://github.com/ananthonline/graffiti

This works great for me, YMMV. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this mean that you actually have to add the file to project a) then add it as a link to project b)? Because that's pretty much exactly the scenario I was trying to avoid...

Comment: I add it as a link to BOTH projects manually. Since my file count isn't too large, I can do this. I might consider Marc Gravell's method if the number of files increases at a later date.