# Common library for Windows Phone and Android App projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xamarin.android

I am developing a windows phone app and an android app. Both the apps are under one visual studio 2010 solution.

I wanted to include a third project under the same solution which contains common functionality that both windows and android app uses. So, for this when I use plain 'Class Library' and when I try to reference that in windows phone app project, it says "Unable to add the selected project reference. The project reference must be another Silverlight for Windows Phone project that is same or lower version".

Which type of project do you suggest, so that I can use it windows phone and android projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use two different csproj files - because the build targets and other pieces will be different for the two platforms. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620187/802203) recursive include in each csproj to add the sources from a common location.

You can also try to use the [Portable class library](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/) extension but I'm not sure if it will help.