# Linq to SQL object in Win Phone 8

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a Class Library which contains a Linq to SQL object which is then connected to a database. I also have a WCF Service for other apps.

I now decided to use the same database in a Windows Phone 8 application, so connected to the Web Service which was fine. Some of the methods require a Customer object so i tried to import the DLL library with Linq to Sql and i got an error that it cant be imported (*unable to add specified project reference. the reference must be a windows phone project*).

I done a search on this and found some threads with similar issues but nothing to state what workarounds if any i could use to connect to a WCF Web service which accepts a Customer object as part of its method.

So is there a workaround? Does the service need to be recreated from scratch? Or any other alternatives.

Comment: Did you try to add the DLL itself, or the project?

Comment: I added a reference (dll) to the phone project but wouldnt allow me to and gave the error listed above.

Comment: See if this answer helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11659270/745969

Comment: Thanks - the more i read into all this the more i think i should create a New WP8 app and create the Customer object within the solution (just to avoid confusing myself) and use that to pass it into the service - would this be possible? Or would i find a new issue down that line?

Comment: That should work - I don't think you'd run into any issues that way.