# How to organize an XNA content project to allow editing of game scripts pre-run and at runtime

Tags: c#, xna

Right now in my XNA solution I have 2 projects, my main XNA game project and an XNA content project.  I am beginning to expose some aspects of my game to a scripting engine with the main intention to allow myself to be able to change behaviors and data without having to close my game, recompile, restart.

Right now when I make a new build it creates the binaries in the C:\solution\project\bin\x86\Debug directory, and copies all the data from the content project into C:\solution\project\bin\x86\Debug\content.  The problem I am trying to solve is where to put my game scripts so they are both accessible by the game at runtime, but also editable before and during runtime and not risk changes being overwritten by the rebuild/copy process on the next go.

If the scripts are in my content project and I edit them during runtime, the only way I can see to load changes of the script is to check both C:\solution\project\bin\x86\Debug\Scripts and compare it to the same script file in C:\solution\projectContent\Scripts and load whichever is newer.  This seems iffy and requires hardcoding paths.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't even get at these paths at runtime on Windows Phone or XBox - so you're presumably asking about XNA on Windows (if yes, please clarify that in your question).

If your files don't need to be processed by the Content Pipeline in any way, I would recommend that you put them in a common location identified by [Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). This value works in the XNA framework (although I am not sure where it will point to on platforms other than a PC).

As for your development setup, you can [include these files using a wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620187/802203) and [environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

A simple pre-build batch file could copy these files to the common location if they don't exist already - that way people who check out your code don't need to manually copy these files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I guess that  adds to the question of how do I make the scripts editable when running on the pc in development but the scripts still viewable by the game when running on wp7 or xbox?

Comment: As I mentioned - the scripts will be editable on the PC because they are both edited and loaded from  SpecialFolder.ApplicationData - and on XBox or WP7 they should still be accessible to run from there (the documentation states this value works on XNA). They just won't be accessible to edit, that's all.