# Visual Studio project linking files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have two Visual Studio projects. One targets .NET 4.0, the other one .NET 3.5. They should have the same source.

I don't want to make a copy of the source code because I would have to keep them manually synchronized. I would also like to avoid linking files one by one because I would also need to do some upkeep when adding/removing files.

So, I am using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620187/520229) to add all the files. The problem is that it also adds AssmblyInfo.cs. Is there a way link all source files from another project except one?

Comment: This seems a job for a software versioning and revision control system (SVN, GIT or ..... _place here your preferred tool_ ...)

Comment: @Steve How so? That seems strange to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/03/08/546583.aspx) [Exclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx).:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\Foo\**\*.cs" Exclude="..\Foo\**\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```